# Extracting certain products from a webpage using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in Python Scrapy to harvest various product names and price from books.toscrape. The reason I submit this tiny code to Code Review is because, in Python 3 when it comes to work with Scrapy and parse some data from a web, the csv output looks awkward (if the csv is derived from default command, as in `scrapy crawl toscrapesp -o items.csv -t csv`). The results found in such CSV file are with a uniform gap between two lines that means there is a line gap between each two rows. I've fixed it using the below script. I didn't use default command to get the CSV output; rather, I've written few lines of code in spider class and got the desired output.

Although It is running smoothly, I'm not sure it is the ideal way of doing such thing. I expect someone to give any suggestion as to how I can improve this script.

"items.py" includes:

```
import scrapy

class ToscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Price = scrapy.Field()
```

Spider contains:

```
import csv
import scrapy

outfile = open("various_pro.csv", "w", newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

class ToscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "toscrapesp"
    start_urls = ["http://books.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.nav-list a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.collect_data)

    def collect_data(self, response):
        global writer                                  
        for item in response.css('.product_pod'):
            product = item.css('h3 a::text').extract_first()
            value = item.css('.price_color::text').extract_first()
            yield {'Name': product, 'Price': value}  
            writer.writerow([product,value])
```

Please click [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6wglr6kb2y4ey8/line_gap.jpg?dl=0) to see what I was having earlier. Upon executing the script, I get CSV output with no line gap or blank rows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should reinvent the wheel and provide your own CSV export. The following works for me as is (note the addition of `.strip()` calls - though I don't think they are necessary at all):

```
import scrapy


class ToscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "toscrapesp"
    start_urls = ["http://books.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.nav-list a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.collect_data)

    def collect_data(self, response):
        for item in response.css('.product_pod'):
            product = item.css('h3 a::text').extract_first().strip()
            value = item.css('.price_color::text').extract_first().strip()
            yield {'Name': product, 'Price': value}
```

Running it with `scrapy runspider spider.py -o output.csv -t csv` produces a CSV file with no blank lines:

```
Price,Name
£53.74,Tipping the Velvet
£29.69,Forever and Forever: The ...
£55.53,A Flight of Arrows ...
£36.95,The House by the ...
£30.25,Mrs. Houdini
£28.08,The Marriage of Opposites  
...
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your kind reply. The thing is, I had been suffering from this "line gap" issue in the csv output for the last two years. Tried with several different ways but still no luck until I used the way I've shown above. I just ran the script rectifying the portion you suggested with `.strip()`, and got the output with the issue again. I don't know if it happens in my case only or with the people using python 3.5 as well. However, this is the reason I used that customized portion in my spider. Looks a bit awkward but it works. Thanks sir.

Comment: @Mithu got it. Okay, but can you be sure the problem is not with your CSV editor? What if you open the CSV file with a simple text editor - do you still see these blank lines there? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry sir  alecxe, for this delayed response. I was not around. For your observation, I just uploaded a csv file derived from scrapy using your suggested command. What you said is a little bit tricky for me that is why I uploaded it. Perhaps you can understand, what basically the problem is. Thanks sir. Here goes the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv7wfnzivshlu5m/items.csv?dl=0

Comment: @Mithu ah, of course, this is [this windows-specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row). You should probably patch an item exporter like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43394566/771848). Hope that helps.

Comment: One last thing sir: should i have to create this,i meant `scrapy.exporters` or it is located somewhere within scrapy projects like settings.py, middleware.py etc? Thanks sir.

Comment: @Mithu I guess you'll have to have this custom csv item exporter defined ([like this](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/a92c42ed7fd9c94afef9eb95662fed21) - not tested). Then, you have to configure it to be used for csv exporting via scrapy settings, e.g.: `FEED_EXPORTERS = {'csv': 'importable.path.to.CSVNewLineExporter'}`. Then, you can run your spider as `scrapy crawl spidername --set FEED_URI=output.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv`. Let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'll for sure. However, If i stick to the way I've done up here, will there be any problem? Because I have tested with several sites and didn't find any issue getting the results in a csv file . Please, don't get bothered for this prolonged conversation. Thanks sir

Comment: @Mithu I am afraid that's at least reinventing the wheel in some sense and, I am not 100% sure having a file opened in a write mode while asynchronous scrapy callbacks write to it would not cause any problems  in the future. I'd avoid that just to be safe. Thanks.